# When a wizard's familiar attacks, who's the attacker for the purposes of Invisibility?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, familiars, invisibility

The [Invisibility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility) spell states:

> If the subject attacks directly, however, it immediately becomes visible

Who is the attacker when a familiar delivers a touch spell? The familiar, the spellcaster or both?

Answer (score 18):

## The Familiar is the Attacker

From the PFSRD:

> Deliver Touch Spells (Su): If the master is 3rd level or higher, a familiar can deliver touch spells for him. If the master and the familiar are in contact at the time the master casts a touch spell, he can designate his familiar as the “toucher.” The familiar can then deliver the touch spell just as the master would. As usual, if the master casts another spell before the touch is delivered, the touch spell dissipates.

This ability does not specify that the familiar counts as its master for the purposes of making the attack, just that it delivers the touch spell with the same parameters that the master would use. As a result, the default assumption - that the familiar is another creature and is treated as such - takes effect.

Comment: How would this tie in with the Share Spells ability? Normally invisibility only affects a single target but if the mage casts it on themselves they can affect their familiar as well. Would ending it on one end it for the other or would it work like invisibility sphere? (If the caster ends it it's over, if another recipient ends it only they appear).

Comment: Neither, actually. The spells are separate, just as if you'd used a "mass" version of the spell. Dispel it on the familiar and the master is unaffected, and vice-versa. Buff the familiar with invisibility when you cast it on yourself and if the familiar attacks only the familiar appears.

Comment: That is a great question for another topic.