# Does an invisible familiar delivering a touch spell have advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, invisibility, touch-attacks

Since a warlock's familiar can be a [Quasit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quasit) (which can turn *invisible*) and a familiar can be used to deliver the warlock's touch spell, it should be able to deliver a touch spell like [*plane shift*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift)<sup>1</sup> (when used on unwilling creatures) while invisible.

But does the familiar get advantage on the attack? The wording of the Unseen Attackers section is quite specific about saying “you”, which I interpret as the caster, not the familiar:

> When a creature can’t see **you**, you have advantage on attack rolls against it.

Does the Advantage apply or not?

---

1) Plane Shift is horrible as an offensive spell. However, this question might be relevant for Multiclassed warlocks.

Comment: Related Pathfinder question: [When a wizard's familiar attacks, who's the attacker for the purposes of Invisibility?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31965/when-a-wizards-familiar-attacks-whos-the-attacker-for-the-purposes-of-invisib?rq=1)

Comment: @Bash very good point, but now that I was looking, I did not find any offensive Warlock spells with the range of touch. If you do, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: If you don't like the pact of the chain warlock + plane shift example, you do not need multiclassing to use another one : a simple wizard could cast invisibility once, and benefit from 2 different touch spell attacks (one from the familiar and one from himself) ; or a pact of the chain warlock may learn shocking grasp using a feat. But you are right, a sorcerer/warlock will have most uses of this trick.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Yes, advantage applies

Why?  The **you** in the unseen attackers sections is referring to whatever creature is invisible / can't be seen.  In this case it is your familiar, and it would have advantage even though it uses your attack modifier.

Comment: This is important - otherwise only PCs would ever benefit from invisibility.